How can I get packet data in Wireshark from npcap packet
I have a packet file that works with Wireshark and the automated npcap system that is installed. Upon executing the file (double clicking), I get loads of line entries with text. I am trying to get the packets data that it contains, if any. I would provide detailed screenshots of my process but I am on a mobile device and am unable to provide the images.
I’ve tried opening the parts where it says encrypted data truncated, it showed me text that I couldn’t decrypt and I’m pretty sure it wasn’t the data I was looking for.
I’ve tried using the data plaintext function in file, but it didn’t return any readable data and took abnormally long to load.
I’m almost 100% sure that the text would be decrypt able (if encrypted at all) and human readable in the end

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I looked through the no cap file for hours and found the data smh

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
